# Communicating between NodeJS and Arduino through SerialPort

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to get a message from my Arduino to NodeJS using SerialPort. Here is my NodeJS code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421',{
  baudRate: 9600
});

port.on('data',(data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And here is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Message");
    delay( 1000 );
}
```

It's working. However, the message I am receiving looks like this:

```
<Buffer 4d 65 73>
<Buffer 73 61 67 65>
<Buffer 0d 0a>
```

I've tried a lot of different things to try and read the message properly. If it makes a difference I would eventually like my message to be JSON. Here are a few things I have tried:

I've added this:

```
parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
```

I think that might be out dated, as I get `readline` is not a function errors messages.

I have tried using a Readline object:

```
var parser = new Readline();
parser.on('data', function(data){console.log( data );});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ends up I was looking at the wrong documentation. The version of SerialPort I was using is 6.x, most of the help out there is for a much older version. The solution was in the GitHub most recent examples:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n'
});

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1', {
  baudRate: 9600
});

port.pipe(parser);

parser.on('data', console.log);
```

The process of parsing has changed dramatically.

https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/blob/master/examples/readline.js